# Grails 3 rest profile 422 Unprocessable Entity result on show action

Tags: hibernate, rest, http, grails, http-headers

I am having troubles with that and I am not being able to handle it and I didn´t find any answer here.

I have an application in Grails 3.1.10, with rest profile, I have some Domain Classes and their respective Controllers, I can create new objects with POST to save action, update them with PUT to update action and list them with GET to index action, but I am not being able to get a proper response in a GET to show action.

I am not sure if the issue that I have is in the request or in the application

My UrlMappings is like this:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
       constraints {
           // apply constraints here
       }
```

I also tried with

```
get "/resources/$id"(controller:"resource", action:"show")
```

And same result: 422: Unprocessable Entity, "errors": [10] 0:  {
"message": "Property [] of class [class ] cannot be null" "path": "/1" "_links": { "self": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/1" }- }-}
For every single property different to id.

I am doing an http get request to http://localhost:8080/resource/show/1 (or http://localhost:8080/resources/1 in the second configuration), with the followings headers: "Content-Type: application/json" and "Authorization: Bearer " (I am using spring security rest plugin to secure the application). The same request to http://localhost:8080/resource/index (or to http://localhost:8080/resources/ in the second configuration) worked perfect and returned me a json with all the objects.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check one of this two options:

1. Use @Resource in your domain class and do nnot create a controller(grails generates it automatically in this case)
2. If you want to have a bit more control, you can use an url mapping resource +  a Controller that extends RestfulController as described in the documentation section 10.1.5.1 (http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#webServices)

In this second options you will need something like this in the URlMappings:

```
"/books"(resources:"book")
```

and also a controller like:

```
class BookController extends RestfulController {
  static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
  BookController() {
    super(Book)
  }
}
```